# Upgrade gcc version in Ubuntu 18,04

Tags: gcc, windows-subsystem-for-linux, c++

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 in WSL, which I use to compile my c++ programs.

I need to write a program that gets the name of all the files in a certain directory and adds them into a vector of strings. Browsing the internet I found that I can use the "filesystem" library to do this in a simple and easy way.

The problem is that whenever I try using this answer I get the error `'filesystem' has not been declared`. I suspect this happens because I may not have the filesystem library installed.

I already found a way to fix it by using experimental features and adding a flag to the compilation command, but I still wonder if there is some way to update my gcc package to one that has the library already installed.

My current gcc version is 7.5.0.

Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`filesystem` is experimental in g++-7.5.0.

You should still be able to use it by including it as `<experimental/filesystem>` (which provides namespace `std::experimental::filesystem`), and linking `libstdc++fs` explicitly (with `-lstdc++fs` on the g++ command line), as described in [Filesystem in C++17](https://carlosvin.github.io/langs/en/posts/recursive-directory-iterator/)

Alternatively, you can install `g++-9` (or even `gcc-10`) in bionic from the [toolchain-r PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/ubuntu/test).